# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity - How can I keep a user logged in after changing their password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I'm building my first ASP.NET MVC app and I would like the user to remain logged in whenever they change their password and are redirected to the home page.

I am using SecurityStamp to enable 'Log Off Everywhere' when the user signs in somewhere else.  I have the validateInterval set to 0.  So far this functionality works fine, if I log in using another browser the original session logs out when another request is made.

The issue I am having now is that I would like the user to remain logged in and be redirected to the home screen (not the login page) when they update their password.  **Is it possible to do this?**

My change password controller looks like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           return View(model);
        }
         var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
         if (result.Succeeded)
         {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);                    
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                   // go to welcome page
                 }
          }
    }
```

I am confused about the order in which I need to change the password, update the security stamp, and sign the user in.  Do I also need to sign them out before signing them back in?

Comment: have you tried a redirect to action after you sign them in?

Comment: Yes I have a RedirectToAction in place - it is during this redirect that the user fails the [Authorize] attribute on the welcome route